Input method for diacritics in US Int. with Dead Keys
I use an American laptop keyboard to write in Portuguese with the US Intl. with dead keys configuration. I used to input all the diacritics and special characters with the key sequences that are shown here, that is:

' + e = é
` + e = è
~ + n = ñ
^ + e = ê
" + e = ë
' + c = ç

Since 2016 half the applications that I use (web browsers, for instance) do not accept these key sequences to produce the diacritics, only the diacritics that involve simultaneous use of the right Alt key will work. This kills my ability to touch-type and leaves me no option for some characters such as ã, õ, à, â ô and ê. Is there an explanation/solution for this phenomenon?
